# stuck in Image not showing with php $_GET method inside the <a href=>

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, get

So this are the array associative :

```html
 <?php
 $buku = [
    ['judul' => 'Algoritma & pemrograman menggunakan Java',
      'reason' => 'Buku ini sangat membantu saya dalam mengembangkan skill java dan konsep algoritma yang saya peroleh.',
      'penerbit' => 'Abdul Kadir',
      'pic' => '<img src = "asset/buku1.jpg">'],
      
      ['judul' => 'Webmaster Series: JavaScript',
      'reason' => 'Buku ini sangat membantu saya dalam mengembangkan skill JavaScript yang telah saya peroleh dari kegiatan kuliah.',
      'penerbit' => 'Andi & Wahana Komputer', 'pic' => '<img src="asset/buku2.jpg">'],
      
      ['judul' => 'Zero To One',
      'reason' => 'Buku ini sangat memotivasi saya untuk selalu meng<i>explore</i> pengetahuan / hal-hal yang baru , berkarya, dan menata masa depan agar lebih tersusun rapih sehingga membuat mimpi menjadi nyata.',
      'penerbit' => 'Peter Thiel with Blake Masters',
      'pic'=> '<img src="asset/buku3.jpg">'],
      
      ['judul' => 'Smart Trik: JQuery without plugin',
      'reason' => 'Buku ini sangat membantu saya dalam mengembangkan skill JQuery yang telah saya peroleh dari kegiatan kuliah.',
      'penerbit' => 'Rohy',
      'pic'=> '<img src="asset/buku4.jpg">'],
      
      ['judul' => 'Pemrograman Bootstrap',
      'reason' => 'Buku ini sangat membantu saya dalam mengembangkan skill Bootstrap dan web design agar web yang saya buat lebih interaktif terhadap Users, dengan ilmu yang telah saya peroleh dari kegiatan kuliah.',
      'penerbit' => 'Jubilee Enterprise',
      'pic'=> '<img src="asset/buku5.jpg">'],
      
      ['judul' => 'Buku Pintar Pemrograman PHP',
      'reason' => 'Buku ini sangat membantu saya dalam mengembangkan skill php agar web yang saya buat lebih interaktif terhadap Users, dengan ilmu yang telah saya peroleh dari kegiatan kuliah.',
      'penerbit' => 'Dodit Suprianto',
      'pic'=> '<img src="asset/buku6.jpg">'],
      
      ['judul' => 'Unreal Engine 4 with C++ COOKBOOK',
      'reason' => 'Buku ini sangat membantu saya untuk mempermudah  dalam pemembuatan game yang sedang saya buat di Software Unreal Engine 4.',
      'penerbit' => 'William Sherif & Stephen Whittle',
      'pic'=> '<img src="asset/buku7.jpg">'],
      
      ['judul' => 'Pemrograman Mobile App berbasis Android',
      'reason' => 'Buku ini sangat membantu saya untuk menambah ilmu saya dalam pemembuatan aplikasi di Smartphone berbasis Android.',
      'penerbit' => 'Nazruddin Safaat H',
      'pic'=> '<img src="asset/buku8.jpg">'],
      
      ['judul' => 'Artificial Intelligence',
      'reason' => 'Buku ini sangat membantu saya untuk menambah ilmu saya dalam memahami kecerdasaan perangkat lunak maupun perangkat keras.',
      'penerbit' => 'INFORMATIKA',
      'pic'=> '<img src="asset/buku9.jpg">'],
      
      ['judul' => 'Real-Time Communication with WebRTC',
      'reason' => 'Buku ini sangat membantu saya untuk menambah ilmu saya dalam pembuatan aplikasi real-time text/video chat.',
      'penerbit' => 'Salvatore Loreto',
      'pic'=> '<img src="asset/buku10.jpg" >']
 
     ];
?>
```

and this are printing the array inside the span in the same page with the array:

```html
`<?php foreach ($buku as $book) :  ?>
   <div class="frame">
    <span class="gambar"><?php echo $book['pic']; ?></span> 
    <span class="judul"><a href="latihan3.php?judul=<?=$book['judul'];?>&&reason=<?=$book['reason']; ?>&&penerbit=<?=$book['penerbit']; ?>&&pic=<?=$book['pic'];?> <?php echo $book["judul"]; ?></a> </span>
  <span class="reason"><?php echo "<u>Alasan</u> : ".$book['reason'];?></span>
 </div>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

[So this are the result if i put the "> that missing on the "a" tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZDFP.png)

then, this are the $_GET Superglobal method for catching the data of an array in different page from the array:

```html
<ul class="profil">
    <div class="pic"><?php echo $_GET["pic"]; ?></div>
   
    <li>Judul: <?php echo $_GET["judul"]; ?></li>
    <li>Alasan: <?php echo $_GET["reason"]; ?></li>
    <li>Penerbit: <?php echo $_GET["penerbit"]; ?></li> 
   </ul>
```

Finally, The problem is that get superglobal doesn't catch the picture if i click the title/judul on the span which is i already putted the link inside the  title/judul class of the span...

Please help me guys, i tried for 2 days to figured this out but null result -_-

thanks in advance

Comment: You have failed to show what the HTML looks like.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams wait, what do you mean?

Comment: This would be a lot easier to answer if your code was formatted in a clearer way

Comment: @DarrenH i'm sorry before, i'm pretty new in this site which is i'm not familiar enough with the feature :D

Comment: @DarrenH done clearing :D i hope you could help me, tho

Comment: Please check my answer to know where was your error so that you learn and avoid such errors in the future. Also the solution for your current case is posted. Current answer doesn't highlight the problem and should not be the most correct answer. @Fidelramadhan

Comment: Did my answer solve your question?  It defines out the error so that you learn and avoid it in the future. Besides, it recommends a good-practice solution the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't use image name only "boku7.jpg" for example, why do you need the whole html tag in your url?

Comment: btw, i use the whole img html tag because the image is in different folder

Comment: And i tried ur suggestion (i wrote like this 'pic' => 'asset/buku7.jpg'), but instead its only printing the whole data inside the pic index from the array

Comment: 'pic' => 'asset/buku7.jpg' thats right, but you have to change your html code after that:
    <span class="gambar"><img src="<?php echo $book['pic']; ?>"/></span>

Comment: damn, u solved my nightmare.. so i changed the array as you told me before and i add the the img src tag on the get method that use for catch the data from the array... Big thanks man!

Comment: you are welcome, the problem was actually in the double quote you use inside your 'pic' value.
if your replace the double quote with a single quote your old code will work also 'pic' => '<img src=\'asset/buku1.jpg\' />'
good luck.

Comment: i already did that, but still the image on the different page (after click the title/judul of the span) are not show up.. so the main problem is only the span is doesn't have an img src tag

Answer (score 0):

The a tag isn't closed yet. ">" is missing before the image

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with your current data and code, and with this small change your application will work properly. So, Instead of using

```
pic=<?=$book['pic'];?>
```

to build your query string, just use

```
pic=<?=urlencode($book['pic']);?>">
```

The problem is that you're trying to write some HTML characters that the browser will interpret and causes a wrong built `<a>` tag. This results in unintended behavior.

But it's **recommended** to abstract your data to just raw links, array of `image.jpg` for example, and let your application handle them.